# Edit Models in different MVC project layer

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3, data-access-layer, sql-update

I have a ASP.NET MVC3 solution named "SampleProject". I have 4 projects in the solution.

The project names of the solution are

**SampleProject.Data** (holds entity classes, DAL classes, and filter classes)

**SampleProject.Service** (something like BLL in standard ERP)

**SampleProject.Tests** (test project)

**SampleProject.Web** (holds controllers and views)

**I am calling the Service classes from my controllers. The service classes are calling Data classes and data classes are performing the database operations.**

I have done create, list and details part. Now I stucked in Edit part. None of the examples (NerdDinner,MVCMusicStore etc) using my architecture. In the provided examples(NerdDinner,MVCMusicStore etc or in ASP.NET website tutorials), they are just using built in **UpdateModel method which I don't want to use**. I want to manually get the model object from my view and send it to my Data layer for update.

My question is, how can I update the models through different project layer?

Comment: Maybe you can give an example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the porblem. Here is the code.Just for reference, CResult is a class which contains IsSuccess(bool), Message(string) properties in it.

```
CResult oCResult;
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Restaurant model)
    {

        try
        {
            oCResult = restaurantService.Update(model);
            if (oCResult.IsSuccess)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View("Error");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

The view engine prepares the object (in my case, it is Restaurant type of object) it inherits with new values and send back to controller. this is my understanding.